# why web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log) returns 0

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

I have build a Ethereum Full Node in Ubuntu 18.04. `geth` is running through the following command:

`nohup geth --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 -rpcport 8545 --rpc -rpcapi "wb3,admin,eth,personal,net" --ws --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins "*" --datadir "/data/ethereum" --syncmode fast --maxpeers 10000 --cache 8196 >> geth.log 2>&1 &`

one line of geth.log content:

```
INFO [06-06|00:59:22.250] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.793ms     number=10206927 hash="92683d…04062d"
```

`truffle` is configured as the following:

```
development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    }
```

In truffle console, when I use command `web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)`, it just returns

```
0
undefined
```

Why is it not 10206927(from geth.log) or a close number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a bit odd, you could try the same and check with the geth console

Answer (score 2):

maybe the `web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)` returns `0` because `geth` has not yet starterd the block synchronization but only the headers import.

When the import of the headers will be completed and the blocks sync will start, the `web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)` probably will return a non-zero value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the case your node is syncing, then do:

```
   this.web3.eth.isSyncing((error: Error, sync: any) => {
        if (!error && sync) {
            console.log(sync.currentBlock);
            console.log(sync.highestBlock);
        }
    });
```